# Как удалить определенный тег внутри тега?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста с регуляркой в PHP.
Мне необходимо удалить тег `<br>` только внутри секций `<ul>` и `<li>` не затрагивая остальной текст

```html
<ul>
<br>
<li>Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over <br>matches or the expression </li>
<br>
<li>for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.</li>
<br>
</ul>

The side bar includes a Cheatsheet, full Reference,<br> and Help. You can also Save & Share with the Community, and view patterns you create or favorite in My Patterns.

<ul>
<br>
<li>Edit the Expression & Text to see matches. Roll over <br>matches or the expression </li>
<br>
<li>for details. PCRE & JavaScript flavors of RegEx are supported. Validate your expression with Tests mode.</li>
<br>
</ul>
```

Comment: так внутри ul или внутри li?

Comment: Нужно и там и там

Comment: $newText = str_replace("<br>", "", sourceTEXT); Ну а если по регуляркам: $newText = preg_replace("(<br>)", "", $sourceText);

Comment: @Blackmeser не позорься.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно с помощью `preg_replace_callback`

```
$result = preg_replace_callback("/<ul>(.*?)<\/ul>/ius", function($ul){
                  return strip_tags($ul[0], '<ul><li>');                
             }, $txt);
```